# Android ActionBar always null in CordovaPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-actionbar, cordova-plugins

I am trying to show the Android ActionBar in Cordova application. I have the following code snippets.

**MainActivity:**

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  public class ActionBar extends CordovaActivity 
  {
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
     super.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     super.init();
     // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
     super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
     //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
     getActionBar();
    }
 }
```

**Plugin:**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class ActionBarPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

static Activity ctx;
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    try {
        ctx = (Activity)cordova;
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ctx.getActionBar();
                callbackContext.success(); 
            }
        });
        return true;
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + error.getMessage());
        callbackContext.error(error.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

But still I am not able to get the ActionBar for this application. The **ctx.getActionBar()** always returns **NullPointer Exception**.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is any other way to get the ActionBar for Cordova application?

Comment: Is any suggestion to get the ActionBar for Cordova application?

Answer (score 0):

We need to do the following for showing Actionbar,

**1. Set preferences in Config.xml:**

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true" />
```

**2. Set theme to Holo or AppCompat in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Now `((Activity)cordova).getActionBar()` will not be **"null"**